# Searching objects nearby using radius. Google maps

Tags: java, android, mysql, location

I'm trying to find places that are in approximately 20 meters from my current location. I've got co-ordinates of this places in my database (MySQL).
What I need is to take this co-ordinates out of database and compare it somehow to mine. If certain "pin" is closer that 20 meters the simple toast communicate should occur.

Firstly, I need help with getting current location from database

I'm using android studio.

Comment: _getting current location from database_ ?

Comment: IMHO, get your current location on device, then send to server and finally receive the calculated result set (the places in 20 m around you)

Comment: getting location of these places, that are already in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iam not giving you the exact answer, but i will give you some clues.

Best way of handing these type of problem is to let the sql do the magic and return the results depending on the radius and the coordinates.

Here is a sample sql query

```
public function gettemples($latitude, $longitude, $distance, $templetype, $limitno){
        $this->connect();
        // $query = "SELECT * FROM temples";

        $query = "SELECT *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(".$latitude.") ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * 
            cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(".$longitude.") ) + sin( radians(".$latitude.") ) * 
            sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM temples HAVING
            distance < ".$distance." ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , ".$limitno."";
                $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
                $result = $stmt->execute();
                $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                return $results;
    }
```